# Web Fonts not working in some Firefox (including Google Fonts Sample Page)

Tags: webfonts, google-webfonts

[image: Firefox 21v, Windows 7 32Bit]
[Firefox 21v, Windows 7 32Bit](http://www.google.com/fonts)

We are about to use Google Fonts for an upcoming project. We've found two computers with Firefox which doesn't display any web fonts at all.(Chrome display them correctly) All our computers has Firefox 21.0 version. Seems it's something related to the OS or Firefox dependency. Is this known bug for Firefox?  (Assuming the Google Fonts page has correct css rules for embeded font)

Comment: We're experiencing the exact same issue! The web-fonts were rendering properly until yesterday. Since this morning, Firefox didn't render any web-fonts at all.

Comment: Even after reinstating the Firefox, the result is same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the default protocol `http://` with `https://` - it worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't seem the ideal solution, but it worked for me too.