# Included google webfont not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm trying to use a google font like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 2em;
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see I've tried with `http` and `https` as suggested in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584224/web-fonts-not-working-in-some-firefox-including-google-fonts-sample-page/19265560#19265560) but nothing seems to work.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Also as you can see the font takes the fallback `serif` font. Now why is the `line-height` changing when removing the font which is not even used?

[image]

I'm using Google Chrome Version: 52.0.2743.116

And the real question is: How to include the google font?

As it seems to be loaded from dev tools [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the site in incognito mode, maybe some browser plugins meddle with your code. I've created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sasoqonaja/edit?html,js,output) based on your code and it works perfectly fine, I also saved it on my hard drive and it also works. Checked on the exact same version of Chrome as yours.

Edit: **Problem solved**. After some investigation and trial and error, it turned out in that in order for this to work for Caramba, he had to modify the font-family from the body styles to include three comma-separated values for this to work, so

```
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', serif;
```

did not work, while

```
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, serif;
```

did.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I get the serif font in jsbin also with incognito mode :(

Comment: What does the network tab in chrome dev tools show? Does the page load the http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic resource and the http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v9/ODelI1aHBYDBqgeIAH2zlJbPFduIYtoLzwST68uhz_Y.woff2 resource successfully?

Comment: Good catch! I've updated the question with a print screen showing that the `css?family` is loaded!

Comment: Ok, so the css file is loading but actual font files don't. This means the the browser analyzed your html and figured out none of the content matches the font variants specified in the css file loaded from google. Try adding `font-style: normal` and `font-weight: 300` to the styles of the body.

Comment: Added and updated the question, no change at all. Everything is the same as before.

Comment: I've modified my jsbin to include the font base64-encoded. Does it work for you now? http://jsbin.com/lexezupumu/edit?html,js,output  If yes, you might want to copy the font files and serve them locally.

Comment: Thank you! That does work indeed! Still wondering why ...!? But it's a big help for now to use it like that! maybe you include the last comment into your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120769/discussion-between-wojciech-slowacki-and-caramba).